# Is There any Expression Statement Similar to CHARINDEX?

Tags: sql-server

I have to implement a where clause which should give me the matching substring.

Eg: I have a column destination email in a table called `Email`. I will send an email to one of the "destination email" plus other id (..@example.com).
I am storing all the email addresses added to the "TO Section" of an email (`varTo"`)

Right now, I am using the below query:

```
    select * from table where destinationEmail= CHARINDEX(DestinationEmail, varTo)>0.
```

Currently, I am facing an issue with 2 email addresses (rsa_papers@example.com and sa_papers@example.com) which is returning 2 rows. For other emails, this condition returns the correct values without any issues

The exact result what I  want is the system should pick the email which exist in the "destinationEmail" and should ignore other emails stored in the `varTo` section.

Eg: I am sending an email to RSA_papers@example.com; natraj@ex.com; manoj@ex.com. Here, it should return only "RSA_papers@example.com"

Is it possible to achieve this using a simple where condition?

Many thanks,
Manoj

Comment: In MySql should not exists the CHARINDEX() function  .. could be yoy are referring to MS SQLSERVER ???  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html

Comment: Have you checked MySQL documentation for this?  Research is part of programmer's job.

Comment: @acarlstein, yes i am referring to MS SQLSERVER

Comment: @Naraj, I think your comment is for scaisEdge since he is the one asking not me.

Comment: @scaisEdge yes i am referring to MS SQLSERVER

Comment: @scaisEdge could you help me here?

Comment: @Natraj  . the use of value separated  by semicolon is a bad design  .. you should normalize the content  ..  in a specific table  ..or manage these result with your server side language  ..